# How to get only the 1st appearing key when having multiple duplicate values in nested object - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, javascript-objects

I have the following JavaScript nested object:

```
    let menu = {
    vegetarian: {
        plainPizza: 100,
        redChilliPizza: 150,
        cheesePizza: 200,
        capsicumPizza: 160,
        onionPizza: 200
    },
    nonVegetarian: {
        supremeMeatPizza: 100,
        meatPizza: 130,
        meatLoversPizza: 160,
        chickenPizza: 200,
        chilliMeatPizza: 200
    }
};

let minimumPrice = 100;
let maximumPrice = 200;
```

I need to show Pizzas between the given price range but want to show the Pizza only that is coming 1st and having price same for other pizzas. For example for a Pizza of Rs. 100 I just want to show only 'plainPizza', not others in my results. And same for others too. I got the price range results but are with all Pizza. Here's my code below:

```
    function searchUsingPriceRangeFromMenu(mainObject, minimumPrice, maximumPrice) {
    for (let key in mainObject) {
        let arrOfPriceRangeKeys = [];
        if (typeof mainObject[key] !== "object" && mainObject[key] >= minimumPrice && mainObject[key] <= maximumPrice) {
            arrOfPriceRangeKeys = key;
            document.write(arrOfPriceRangeKeys + "<br>")
        } else {
            if (typeof mainObject[key] === "object") {
                searchUsingPriceRangeFromMenu(mainObject[key], minimumPrice, maximumPrice, arrOfPriceRangeKeys)
            }

        }
    } return;
}
searchUsingPriceRangeFromMenu(menu, minimumPrice, maximumPrice);
```

My Results:

```
plainPizza
redChilliPizza
cheesePizza
capsicumPizza
onionPizza
supremeMeatPizza
meatPizza
meatLoversPizza
chickenPizza
chilliMeatPizza
```

So please tell me what I need to do is and where? All I want to end up with as following:

```
plainPizza
redChilliPizza
cheesePizza
capsicumPizza
meatPizza
```

help me.

Comment: what `arrOfMenuKeys[i] == arrOfMenuValues[i];`  is supposed to do ?

Comment: @AbbasEbadian, using arrOfMenuKeys[i] == arrOfMenuValues[i]; I'm displaying the name of the key(s) which is equivalent to value(s). I hope I'm clear with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array which will hold already written prices then in every iterate, check if current price is present in that array or not.

```js
let menu = {
    vegetarian: {
        plainPizza: 100,
        redChilliPizza: 150,
        cheesePizza: 200,
        capsicumPizza: 160,
        onionPizza: 200
    },
    nonVegetarian: {
        supremeMeatPizza: 100,
        meatPizza: 130,
        meatLoversPizza: 160,
        chickenPizza: 200,
        chilliMeatPizza: 200
    }
};

let minimumPrice = 100;
let maximumPrice = 200;

    function searchUsingPriceRangeFromMenu(mainObject, minimumPrice, maximumPrice) {
    for (let key in mainObject) {
        let arrOfPriceRangeKeys = [];
        if (typeof mainObject[key] !== "object" && mainObject[key] >= minimumPrice && mainObject[key] <= maximumPrice && !printedPrices.includes(mainObject[key])) {
            //pay attention to last part of condition
            printedPrices.push(mainObject[key]); // push the new price
            arrOfPriceRangeKeys = key;
            document.write(arrOfPriceRangeKeys + "<br>")
        } else {
            if (typeof mainObject[key] === "object") {
                searchUsingPriceRangeFromMenu(mainObject[key], minimumPrice, maximumPrice, arrOfPriceRangeKeys)
            }

        }
    } return;
}
let printedPrices = []; //new array
searchUsingPriceRangeFromMenu(menu, minimumPrice, maximumPrice);
```

Comment: @AbbasEbadian-Your answer to my question is really helpful and it worked. If you are available, could you please help me again ASAP when I changed my object to a nested object. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you again for your support. @AbbasEbadian

Comment: please go through the link below and help me again only If you are free. My mean is not to bother you again and again but as a beginner I find your answers very much understandable. @AbbasEbadian https://stackoverflow.com/q/65940905/15069520

Answer (score 0):

You can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the list of [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) from the `menu` to be not only in the given price range, but also [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the first key for the current price.

```js
let menu = {
  capsicumPizza: 450,
  onionPizza: 530,
  pepperoniPizza: 490,
  mushroomsPizza: 490,
  extraCheesePizza: 600,
  blackOlivesPizza: 580,
  greenPeppersPizza: 490
};
let minimumPrice = 400;
let maximumPrice = 600;

function searchUsingPriceRange(minimumPrice, maximumPrice) {
  return Object.keys(menu)
    .filter((key, _, keys) => {
      const price = menu[key];
      // item is in price range
      return price >= minimumPrice &&
        price <= maximumPrice &&
        // it's the first item with that price
        key === keys.find(item => menu[item] === price)
    })
}

document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML = searchUsingPriceRange(minimumPrice, maximumPrice).join("<br>")
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Besides that, don't use `document.write`. If you use it after the page has finished loading it'll mess up your page.