# how to clear or overwrite document.write() on browser when my next filter(basically a condition) match in JS

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, arrayobject

I have an array of objects.

```
let mainMenu = [
    {
        brand: "Zara",
        type: "Shirt",
        gender: ["Men", "Women", "Boys", "Girls"],
        size: "Small",
        image: "",
        description: "",
        price: "300",
        colour: "Red",
        stock: "10",
        discount: 5,
        rating: "4"
    },
    {
        brand: "Nike",
        type: "Shirt",
        gender: ["Men", "Women", "Boys"],
        size: "Medium",
        image: "",
        description: "",
        price: "600",
        colour: "Red",
        stock: "20",
        discount: 5,
        rating: "5"
    },
    {
        brand: "Adidas",
        type: "Shirt",
        gender: ["Men", "Women"],
        size: "Large",
        image: "",
        description: "",
        price: "700",
        colour: "Red",
        stock: "30",
        discount: 5,
        rating: "5"
    },
    {
        brand: "Puma",
        type: "tShirt",
        gender: ["Boys", "Girls"],
        size: "Small",
        image: "",
        description: "",
        price: "600",
        colour: "Red",
        stock: "40",
        discount: 5,
        rating: "5"
    },
    {
        brand: "Nike",
        type: "tShirt",
        gender: ["Men", "Women", "Girls"],
        size: "Medium",
        image: "",
        description: "",
        price: "400",
        colour: "Red",
        stock: "50",
        discount: 5,
        rating: "4"
    },
    {
        brand: "Zara",
        type: "tShirt",
        gender: ["Women", "Boys", "Girls"],
        size: "Large",
        image: "",
        description: "",
        price: "600",
        colour: "Red",
        stock: "40",
        discount: 5,
        rating: "5"
    },
    {
        brand: "USPA",
        type: "Jeans",
        gender: ["Men"],
        size: "Small",
        image: "",
        description: "",
        price: "2000",
        colour: "Red",
        stock: "30",
        discount: 5,
        rating: "4"
    },
    {
        brand: "Adidas",
        type: "Jeans",
        gender: ["Women"],
        size: "Medium",
        image: "",
        description: "",
        price: "2500",
        colour: "Red",
        stock: "20",
        discount: 5,
        rating: "5"
    },
    {
        brand: "Puma",
        type: "Jeans",
        gender: ["Boys"],
        size: "Large",
        image: "",
        description: "",
        price: "3000",
        colour: "Red",
        stock: "10",
        discount: 5,
        rating: "4"
    }
];

let filteredArr = [];
filteredArr = mainMenu;
```

I want to search for a Shirt, if exist then want show using `document.write()`. My input is: `let searchForType = "Shirt";`.

My code is:

```
function fetchItemsByType() {
    let isItemAva = filteredArr.filter(obj => obj["type"] === searchForType);
    isItemAva.forEach(obj => {
        for (let i = 0; i < obj["type"].length; i++) {
            if (obj["type"] === searchForType) {
            }
        }
        document.write(obj["type"] + " of " + obj["size"] + " size is Available for " + obj["gender"] + "<br>" + "<br>")
    });
    return isItemAva;
}
let getItemsByType = fetchItemsByType();

if (searchForType === searchForType) {
    console.log(getItemsByType);
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Shirt of Small size is Available for Men,Women,Boys,Girls
>
> Shirt of Medium size is Available for Men,Women,Boys
>
> Shirt of Large size is Available for Men,Women
> ```

Next time, I want to Check the availability of Shirt's size. If size is available then again want to show(by document.write()) only result(s) of Shirt's size **not all Shirt's results**. I tried but getting both cases results at the same time. But I want to show only selected size's Shirt(s) in my final output. Below is the code when I enter shirt's size i.e. `'Small'`.

```
function fetchItemsBySize() {
    let isSizeAva = getItemsByType.filter(obj => obj["size"] === searchForSize);
    isSizeAva.forEach(obj => {
        for (let i = 0; i < obj["size"].length; i++) {
            if (obj["size"] === searchForSize) {
            }
        }
        document.write(obj["type"] + " of " + obj["size"] + " size is Available for " + obj["gender"] + "<br>" + "<br>")
    });
    return isSizeAva;
}
let getItemsBySize = fetchItemsBySize();

if (searchForSize === searchForSize) {
    console.log(getItemsBySize);
}
```

Output is:

> ```
> Shirt of Small size is Available for Men,Women,Boys,Girls
>
> Shirt of Medium size is Available for Men,Women,Boys
>
> Shirt of Large size is Available for Men,Women
>
> Shirt of Small size is Available for Men,Women,Boys,Girls
> ```

But I want only

> ```
> Shirt of Small size is Available for Men,Women,Boys,Girls
> ```

any possibility?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a single function for filtering and hand over the type and value for searching.

This approach takes a check for the property and if the value is an array, it checks the items, otherwise it take a comparison with the hand over value.

---

To show the filterd data, you could take an element and replace the result

```js
const
    filter = (array, key, value) => array.filter(object => Array.isArray(object[key])
        ? object[key].includes(value)
        : object[key] === value
    ),
    data = [{ brand: "Zara", type: "Shirt", gender: ["Men", "Women", "Boys", "Girls"], size: "Small", image: "", description: "", price: "300", colour: "Red", stock: "10", discount: 5, rating: "4" }, { brand: "Nike", type: "Shirt", gender: ["Men", "Women", "Boys"], size: "Medium", image: "", description: "", price: "600", colour: "Red", stock: "20", discount: 5, rating: "5" }, { brand: "Adidas", type: "Shirt", gender: ["Men", "Women"], size: "Large", image: "", description: "", price: "700", colour: "Red", stock: "30", discount: 5, rating: "5" }, { brand: "Puma", type: "tShirt", gender: ["Boys", "Girls"], size: "Small", image: "", description: "", price: "600", colour: "Red", stock: "40", discount: 5, rating: "5" }, { brand: "Nike", type: "tShirt", gender: ["Men", "Women", "Girls"], size: "Medium", image: "", description: "", price: "400", colour: "Red", stock: "50", discount: 5, rating: "4" }, { brand: "Zara", type: "tShirt", gender: ["Women", "Boys", "Girls"], size: "Large", image: "", description: "", price: "600", colour: "Red", stock: "40", discount: 5, rating: "5" }, { brand: "USPA", type: "Jeans", gender: ["Men"], size: "Small", image: "", description: "", price: "2000", colour: "Red", stock: "30", discount: 5, rating: "4" }, { brand: "Adidas", type: "Jeans", gender: ["Women"], size: "Medium", image: "", description: "", price: "2500", colour: "Red", stock: "20", discount: 5, rating: "5" }, { brand: "Puma", type: "Jeans", gender: ["Boys"], size: "Large", image: "", description: "", price: "3000", colour: "Red", stock: "10", discount: 5, rating: "4" }];

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filter(data, 'size', 'Small'), null, 4);

setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filter(data, 'type', 'Shirt'), null, 4), 3000);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Nina, For every possible search key (like gender, type, brand etc.), I've to make separate function and use them. For the same, any suggestion?

Comment: but why? if you can take a universal function with the wanted paramters ...

Comment: Because this is a task assigned to me and needed to do accordingly. That's why..

Answer (score 0):

See [Document API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).
If you want to clear the document, you can use `document.open()`.
Or you can try `document.close()` when you expect your next `document.write()` will automatically clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely the answer to the question asked but just a different approach:

If you stop using document.write but instead you add a `<div id="mydiv">` to your html, you can use `document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = "whatever";` to change the div text, so that you can empty it before filling it.

Example:

```js
let mainMenu = [
    {
        brand: "Zara",
        type: "Shirt",
        gender: ["Men", "Women", "Boys", "Girls"],
        size: "Small",
        image: "",
        description: "",
        price: "300",
        colour: "Red",
        stock: "10",
        discount: 5,
        rating: "4"
    },
    {
        brand: "Nike",
        type: "Shirt",
        gender: ["Men", "Women", "Boys"],
        size: "Medium",
        image: "",
        description: "",
        price: "600",
        colour: "Red",
        stock: "20",
        discount: 5,
        rating: "5"
    },
    {
        brand: "Adidas",
        type: "Shirt",
        gender: ["Men", "Women"],
        size: "Large",
        image: "",
        description: "",
        price: "700",
        colour: "Red",
        stock: "30",
        discount: 5,
        rating: "5"
    },
    {
        brand: "Puma",
        type: "tShirt",
        gender: ["Boys", "Girls"],
        size: "Small",
        image: "",
        description: "",
        price: "600",
        colour: "Red",
        stock: "40",
        discount: 5,
        rating: "5"
    },
    {
        brand: "Nike",
        type: "tShirt",
        gender: ["Men", "Women", "Girls"],
        size: "Medium",
        image: "",
        description: "",
        price: "400",
        colour: "Red",
        stock: "50",
        discount: 5,
        rating: "4"
    },
    {
        brand: "Zara",
        type: "tShirt",
        gender: ["Women", "Boys", "Girls"],
        size: "Large",
        image: "",
        description: "",
        price: "600",
        colour: "Red",
        stock: "40",
        discount: 5,
        rating: "5"
    },
    {
        brand: "USPA",
        type: "Jeans",
        gender: ["Men"],
        size: "Small",
        image: "",
        description: "",
        price: "2000",
        colour: "Red",
        stock: "30",
        discount: 5,
        rating: "4"
    },
    {
        brand: "Adidas",
        type: "Jeans",
        gender: ["Women"],
        size: "Medium",
        image: "",
        description: "",
        price: "2500",
        colour: "Red",
        stock: "20",
        discount: 5,
        rating: "5"
    },
    {
        brand: "Puma",
        type: "Jeans",
        gender: ["Boys"],
        size: "Large",
        image: "",
        description: "",
        price: "3000",
        colour: "Red",
        stock: "10",
        discount: 5,
        rating: "4"
    }
];

let filteredArr = [];
filteredArr = mainMenu;

let searchForSize = "Small";

function fetchItemsBySize() {
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = "";

    let isSizeAva = mainMenu.filter(obj => obj["size"] === searchForSize);
    isSizeAva.forEach(obj => {
        for (let i = 0; i < obj["size"].length; i++) {
            if (obj["size"] === searchForSize) {
            }
        }
         document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML + obj["type"] + " of " + obj["size"] + " size is Available for " + obj["gender"] + "<br>" + "<br>";
        //document.write(obj["type"] + " of " + obj["size"] + " size is Available for " + obj["gender"] + "<br>" + "<br>")
    });
    return isSizeAva;
}
let getItemsBySize = fetchItemsBySize();

if (searchForSize === searchForSize) {
    console.log(getItemsBySize);
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">content</div>
```

Comment: Veda, This is a task assigned to me and needed to do using only document.write()

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood it correctly, you don't want to simply append the second output to the previous output, instead you want to clear the previous output and then write the new output.
I think you have two different ways to approach this.

1. You can erase the whole output and then write again, but this time you can omit the lines you are not looking for. Use `document.open()` to have a new empty document.
2. You can use a tag to change the content only of that tag, for example, you could have the t-shirts size stuff to be displayed inside of this new tag, this way you can easily replace the content of the tag without altering the rest of your output. This can be done by giving a div and id like.

```
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

And in your js code...

```
let myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv")
myDiv.innerHTML = "This is my output"
```

Hope this helps... Please, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Alec - I'm new to JS and for now (as a beginner), these approaches will be out of scope for me. If possible, do help me in same code. Thanks in advance.